# Counter-example for interchanging integral and limit

Tags: integration, limits

Consider $f_n \ge 0$ and $f_n \downarrow f$, can you provide a counter example (if it's not true) for

$$  \int f_n d\mu \downarrow \int f d\mu$$

And if the statement above is true, how can I prove it?

I came up with the counter-example below but in my example $f_n$ is NOT monotonically decreasing.

$$f_n = 1/n * I_{[0,n]}(x)$$

Obviously, in this example $f_n \downarrow 0$ and $\int f_nd\mu = 1 \not\to \int 0 d\mu = 0$

To me, this question looks like monotone convergence theorem but instead of having $f_n \uparrow f$, we have $f_n \downarrow f$ !

Thanks very much for your help,

Comment: Note that if any of the $f_n$ are integrable, then the integrals must converge by the dominated convergence theorem. Hence a counter example **must** have all the $f_n$ non-integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &: \text{ if } x < n \\
1 &: \text{ if } x\geq n
\end{cases}
$$
The result is true, however, if there is an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n$ (by the Dominated convergence theorem)

Comment: Assume $\mu$ is lebesgue measure. Could you explain how you calculate the integral of $\int f_n d\mu$ ?

Comment: It is just $+\infty$ for all $n$ (it is just the area of a really long rectangle, after all :)

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it's just weird that when n goes to infinity, how that integral should be calculated. 
Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: As $n$ goes to $+\infty$, $f_n \to 0$.